# How to call an external C function from within Modelica where one of the C function arguments is a void pointer?

Tags: modelica

How to call an external C function from within Modelica where one of the C function arguments is a void pointer? For example, consider the function prototype <<int queue_push_head(Queue* queue, void* data)>>, here <<void* data>> can't seem to map into a Modelica construct.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly call it, so you have to reconsider the design.

When storing a `void*` in a queue (or any other similar data-structure) you are also saying that the pointer will be valid until the item is removed from the queue (or...). So, you would have to write a C-wrapper that takes a double (or whatever you want to store), mallocs an area and puts the double in it and then casts that to `void*`, something like:

```
function queueDouble
  input Queue queue;
  input Real x;
external "C" annotation(Include="void queueDouble(Queue*queue, double x) {
  void*a=malloc(sizeof(double));
  *(double*)(a)=x;
  queue_push_head(queue, a);");
end queueDouble;
```